# Facebook events api: Event member (FQL)

Tags: facebook

I am fetching the event members for facebook events. Till yesterday I was getting the proper counts of members of an event. But suddenly the counts have following issues:

1. For lot of plans on every consecutive request, I am getting random number of members. Strange issue. Seems facebook servers are not synced properly or something similar.
2. Earlier for the same query string (mentioned below), I was getting the correct counts. But now the count is much less. It seems that at least for a few events now they are sending only the members who are connected with our application (we are using facebook connect).

Example: for the following query currently I am getting "31" members. But on event page members count is much more.

```
FQL: FB.Facebook.apiClient.fql_query('SELECT uid, eid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=336671213618', function(result, error){alert(result.length);});

Event page: http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=109411842404023
```

Is there any recent change in facebook API or policies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there have been changes in this Facebook api due to a loop hole

you can read about it [here](http://www.tgdaily.com/security-features/49522-new-privacy-hole-in-facebook-makes-zuckerbergs-party-plans-public)

and the developer who exposed this [loophole](http://zestyping.livejournal.com/256801.html),

I guess you will have to wait till this is sorted out by Facebook